# Metric (TFM) file not found

Tags: fonts

For no apparent reason, my LaTeX suddenly started giving the following error. I have using the LaTeX on this Linux machine (a fedora 14) for 2 years with no problems. I have never seen this error before and the LaTeX file has not been changed as far as I can remember. Can someone explain to me what's happening and what I should do? Thanks.

```
Xy-pic option: Frame and Bracket extension v.3.14 loaded)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/yliow/download/xy-3.8.8/texinputs/xycmtip.tex
Xy-pic option: Computer Modern tip extension v.3.7
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/yliow/download/xy-3.8.8/texinputs/xytips.tex
Xy-pic option: More Tips extension v.3.9
! Font \xy@@alfont=xyluat10 not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again>
\def
l.35 \xyfont@\xy@@blfont
=xylubt10
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Latex code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfarrows,pgfnodes}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=0.04cm,black,<-] (0.0,0.0) -- (1.0,1.0);
\draw[line width=0.1cm,red,->] (3.0,0.0) -- (6.0,2.0);
\draw[line width=0.2cm,red,<->,dashed] (6.0,0.0) -- (9.0,2.0);
\draw[line width=0.1cm,blue,|<->|] (9.0,0.0) -- (12.0,2.0);
\draw[line width=0.05cm,blue,<<->>] (12.0,0.0) -- (15.0,2.0);
\draw[gray] (0.0,0.0) -- (0.0,2);
\draw[gray] (1.0,0.0) -- (1.0,2);
\draw[gray] (2.0,0.0) -- (2.0,2);
\draw[gray] (3.0,0.0) -- (3.0,2);
\draw[gray] (4.0,0.0) -- (4.0,2);
\draw[gray] (5.0,0.0) -- (5.0,2);
\draw[gray] (6.0,0.0) -- (6.0,2);
\draw[gray] (7.0,0.0) -- (7.0,2);
\draw[gray] (8.0,0.0) -- (8.0,2);
\draw[gray] (9.0,0.0) -- (9.0,2);
\draw[gray] (10.0,0.0) -- (10.0,2);
\draw[gray] (11.0,0.0) -- (11.0,2);
\draw[gray] (12.0,0.0) -- (12.0,2);
\draw[gray] (13.0,0.0) -- (13.0,2);
\draw[gray] (14.0,0.0) -- (14.0,2);
\draw[gray] (15.0,0.0) -- (15.0,2);
\draw[gray] (0.0,0.0) -- (15,0.0);
\draw[gray] (0.0,1.0) -- (15,1.0);
\draw[gray] (0.0,2.0) -- (15,2.0);
\draw(0, 0) node [font=\ttfamily, label=below:{\texttt{0}}] {};
\draw(1, 0) node [font=\ttfamily, label=below:{\texttt{1}}] {};
\draw(2, 0) node [font=\ttfamily, label=below:{\texttt{2}}] {};
\draw(3, 0) node [font=\ttfamily, label=below:{\texttt{3}}] {};
\draw(4, 0) node [font=\ttfamily, label=below:{\texttt{4}}] {};
\draw(5, 0) node [font=\ttfamily, label=below:{\texttt{5}}] {};
\draw(6, 0) node [font=\ttfamily, label=below:{\texttt{6}}] {};
\draw(7, 0) node [font=\ttfamily, label=below:{\texttt{7}}] {};
\draw(8, 0) node [font=\ttfamily, label=below:{\texttt{8}}] {};
\draw(9, 0) node [font=\ttfamily, label=below:{\texttt{9}}] {};
\draw(10, 0) node [font=\ttfamily, label=below:{\texttt{10}}] {};
\draw(11, 0) node [font=\ttfamily, label=below:{\texttt{11}}] {};
\draw(12, 0) node [font=\ttfamily, label=below:{\texttt{12}}] {};
\draw(13, 0) node [font=\ttfamily, label=below:{\texttt{13}}] {};
\draw(14, 0) node [font=\ttfamily, label=below:{\texttt{14}}] {};
\draw(15, 0) node [font=\ttfamily, label=below:{\texttt{15}}] {};
\draw(0, 0) node [font=\ttfamily, label=left:{\texttt{0}}] {};
\draw(0, 1) node [font=\ttfamily, label=left:{\texttt{1}}] {};
\draw(0, 2) node [font=\ttfamily, label=left:{\texttt{2}}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please give a Minimum Working Example to help people help you. People need to see the code that produced the error. Obviously you won't give a working example, but give an example which is the minimum you need to demonstrate the problem. There should be information about this somewhere but I have not used this site all that much and I can't find it!

Comment: I've added a short snippet of my latex file that produces the error. The reason why I did not include the code is because it has always been working. I suspect it's not the latex code. Maybe it's something to do with latex or some bizarre issue with file permission??

Comment: It certainly compiles OK here so yes. It is not finding a font. Have you updated your TeX installation at all?

Comment: This was compiled on a fedora 14 machine which is about 2 years old. But the latex has always been working for that past 2 years. (This is a virtual machine -- I have another more recent fedora 19). I was just reading the pdf and thought that I'll just re-make the pdf. Lo and behold, pdflatex cannot finish the job. Since it works for you, I can only conclude that something else is happening .... Anyway, thanks for compiling it on your machine. I'll have to go back to banging my head a little more ...

Comment: By the way, there might be an easier way to plot the tikZ graph. Will you mind posting it as another question? (I am still learning the ins and outs of tikZ as well).

Comment: I know the tikz/pgf looks complicated. But it's generated by a python library. I think the above draws a grid in with some lines, something like this: `p = Plot();
p += Line(x0=9, y0=0, x1=12, y1=2, linecolor='blue', linewidth=0.1,
startstyle='>|', endstyle='>|');
p += Grid();
print p`

Comment: What does kpsewhich xyluat10.tfm give you? If that does not find the tfm, try locate xyluat10.tfm to see if you can find it yourself. If it exists but TeX can't find it, maybe run sudo mktexlsr to remake TeX's databases?

Comment: I've fixed the problem by not using xy. I still don't know why this problem turns up out of nowhere, why it has not appeared for two years, or what happened to the fonts. But since I don't use xy anymore, at least my problem is fixed. Thanks for the comments. (Btw, I do have xypic. I did do texhash.)